# Turing degrees of subsets of Kleene $\mathcal{O}$ which are ordinal notations of subsets of the set of recursive ordinals

Tags: computability, ordinals, turing-machines, ordinal-analysis

An ordinal $\alpha$ is said to be recursive if there is a recursive well-ordering of a subset of the natural numbers having the order type $\alpha$.
The smallest ordinal that is not recursive is called Church–Kleene ordinal, $\omega _{1}^{CK}$.
Kleene $\mathcal{O}$ (a subset of natural numbers) is an ordinal notation for  the set of recursive ordinal $\omega _{1}^{CK}$. Kleene $\mathcal{O}$ is not recursive, not arithmetical and it has Turing degree $\mathcal{O}$ which is an hyperdegree.

Suppose $\alpha$ is a recursive ordinal, let define $K(\alpha)$ as the subset of Kleene $\mathcal{O}$ which is an ordinal notation restricted to any ordinal  $\beta <\alpha$.

What is the smallest $\alpha$  for which $K(\alpha)$ is not recursive?
Assuming such ordinal exist, what is the smallest $\alpha(n)$ for which the Turing degree of $K(\alpha(n))$ is $0^n$, and what about $0^\omega$. Is there an ordinal $\gamma$ for which the Turing degree of $K(\gamma)$  is $0^\gamma$?

I guess $K(\alpha)$  is recursive for all predicative ordinals, what about $K(\Gamma_0)$,  $K(\phi(1,0,0,0))$, $K(\psi (\Omega ^{{\Omega ^{\Omega }}}))$,   $K(\psi_0 (\varepsilon_{\Omega+1}))$, 
$K(\Psi_0(\Omega_\omega))$,  $K(\psi_0 (\varepsilon_{\Omega_\omega+1}))$?

Finally always assuming that there is a recursive ordinal $\alpha$ for which  $K(\alpha)$ is not recursive and $K(\alpha)$  has Turing degree $0^n$, is a there a different ordinal notation for $\alpha$ , let call it  $\hat K(\alpha)$ which is not a subset of Kleene $\mathcal{O}$  and whose Turing degree is $0^m$, with $0^m$<$0^n$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your definition of $K(\alpha)$. If you mean $K(\alpha)$ is the set of notations representing ordinals smaller than $\alpha$, then already $K(\omega+1)$ is non-recursive, and in fact has Turing degree $0''$. Indeed, determining if some notation denotes $\omega$ is equivalent to asking if some machine gives prescribed output for all natural number inputs, which is easily seen to be equivalent to the problem "does a given TM halt for all inputs", which is a prime example of a $0''$ problem. Similarly, $\omega n+1$ is the least for which $K(\alpha)$ has degree $0^{(2n)}$.

Comment: I  know very little about ordinal notation,  I hope to clarify an important point with your comment. You say $K(\omega+1)$ is not recursive.  Why is this notation (which I think is recursive) of all ordinals up to $\omega$  (included) is not admissible : I map $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in $2*n$, and $\omega$ in $1$ and I state that in this notation any even number is less then any odd number. Isn't an ordinal notation just about providing codes which respect the order of the ordinal numbers?

Comment: @Wojowu I forgot to add this to my previous comment which I can not edit any longer

Comment: I posted a related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668199/is-this-a-proper-recursive-ordinal-notation-for-ordinals-omega2

Comment: @holmes You've just described *one specific* notation for $\omega+1$, but there are lots of others. If your $K(\alpha)$ is the set of all notations for ordinals $<\alpha$, then $K(\alpha)$ is not computable as soon as $\alpha\ge\omega$; on the other hand, if you want to focus on one specific set of notations then in general $K(\alpha)$ isn't well-defined (and some possible choices for $K(\alpha)$ will be computable while others won't be).

Comment: @NoahSchweber  by $K(\alpha)$  I mean only one notation, the Kleene notation used in the construction of Kleene's ${\mathcal {O}}$. When I  wrote the question I had a bit of confusion and I see now that the set  $K(\alpha)$  is recursive for any recursive ordinal. I am  impressed about how  Kleene's ${\mathcal {O}}$  is at the same time a limit of a sequence of recursive sets and such an incomputable set (a set with an hyperdegree).

Comment: @holmes There is no **the** Kleene notation. In Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$, every infinite ordinal has infinitely many different notations.

Comment: @NoahSchweber this was indeed also a critical point of confusion. Thank you for clarifying this.  I read this article https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/Church-Kleene_ordinal, but it was not clear to me that it includes  infinite notations.

Comment: @holmes Glancing at that page I find it rather confusing - in general my experiences with googology haven't been that good. At least for the more common topics like [Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O), wikipedia is a much better source (in particular, note that $\mathcal{O}$ is a name for a set of naturals, whereas googology uses the symbol for a particular function).